# Firefox javascript escape error

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, escaping

I have a form on my page which runs a javascript function on submit. This function opens a new window with `window.open(uri,…)`

Since this is a german form there are umlauts and other characters like ß,ä,ö,ü.

So I'm passing the values of the input with `escape(input.value)` to my uri variable.

In Chrome this works perfectly fine and the passed url looks like this

```
index.php?PLZ=&Ort=Ha%DFloch
```

but when I open the site in Firefox it looks like this:

```
index.php?PLZ=&Ort=Ha�loch
```

So how can I achieve the right result in both browsers?

I tried nearly everything from encodeURI to encodeURIcomponent etc…

Comment: Maybe the character are encoded differently in FF and Chrome, because they treat them as being from a different charset. Have you explicitely set the page charset (in a `<meta>` tag)?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, `escape` is deprecated in favour of `encodeURI` and `encodeURIcomponent`. Note that `encodeURI` ignores common characters of an url, like `:` or `/`, so you should use unencoded start of your url `http://example.com/index.php`, then encode the rest with `encodeURIcomponent`.

Comment: [Here](http://www.welde.de/wp-content/themes/welde/auto.html) is my site where I'm having the troubles. Please type in "Haßloch" and see the error when you click "Suchen!"
I've set {charset} and stuff, but you can see it in the source. There is this function haendlersuche where the input values are given via GET to search the database.

Comment: Also: the query works unescaped in Chrome, but Firefox automatically encodes it to this: Ha%C3%9Floch
[See here](http://www.welde.de/wp-content/themes/welde/auto2.html)

Comment: Eh... I've been solving this problem myself some time ago, but I must say that I've yet been unable to write code that encodes it in the same way in Opera and FF, in which I am testing it. However! I still noticed one problem in your code. You set the encoding in `<meta>` to `ISO-8859-1`, but you saved your file in `UTF-8` (you can see it easily in an hex editor - the `ö` character in `öffnen` has two bytes, which happens in UTF-8, not Latin1).

Comment: So now I have it in [Latin1](http://www.welde.de/wp-content/themes/welde/auto3.html) but it doesn't seem to work either…

Answer (score 0):

Use the form to set the character encoding to UTF-8:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8">
```

And set it in the head as well:

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```